# Why is IProgress<T> Report(T) method blocking the UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous

I have a problem with reporting progress within the method Process2() in my code below.  I want to increment the progress bar after every line that is read, but doing so blocks the UI and it becomes unresponsive.  If I comment out the progress.Report() line, it no longer blocks UI thread.  Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it?

Here is fully working code that can be pasted into a starter WPF application.

Click the Run button (there might be a small pause at the beginning for generating the file, wait until after Generating file is Done) and try to move the window around, it remains frozen.

WARNING: this code will generate a text file in your bin\Debug folder (or whatever your configuration is pointing to) It may not be able to write this file if you run this from a network path, thus recommended to run from local disk.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();

        List<string> stringsCollection = new List<string>() { "1_abc123_A_AA_zzz", "2_abc123_AAAA_zzz", "3_abc123_AAAAAA_zzz" };

        int linesCount = 0;
        int totalLines = 0;

        string ASSEMBLY_PATH;
        string file; 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ASSEMBLY_PATH = ReturnThisAssemblyPath();
            file = ASSEMBLY_PATH + @"\test.txt";
            generateFile();
        }

        private async void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            linesCount = 0;

            Progress<int> process2_progress;

            this.progress.Value = 0;
            this.status.Text = "";

            process2_progress = new Progress<int>();
            process2_progress.ProgressChanged += Process2_progress_ProgressChanged;

            this.status.Text += "Searching..." + Environment.NewLine;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                totalLines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(file).Count();

                foreach (string s in stringsCollection)
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
                    {
                        this.status.Text += "Searching " + s + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                    List<string> strCollection = Process2(s, process2_progress);

                    foreach (string str in strCollection)
                        queue.Enqueue(str);
                }
            });

            this.status.Text += "DONE!!" + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        private void Process2_progress_ProgressChanged(object sender, int e)
        {
            linesCount += e;
            this.progress.Value = linesCount * 100 / totalLines;
        }

        List<string> Process2(string inputString, IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(file, new UTF8Encoding()))
            {
                progress.Report(1);
            }

            return result;
        }

    void generateFile()
    {
        this.status.Text += "Generating FIle..." + Environment.NewLine;
        int count = 0;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, true))
        {
            do
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                count++;
            } while (count < 51000);

        }
        this.status.Text += "Done Generating FIle!" + Environment.NewLine;
    }

        public string ReturnThisAssemblyPath()
        {
            string codeBase = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MainWindow)).CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            return System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="status" Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>

        <Button Grid.Row="2" Height="50" Click="Button_Click2">Run2</Button>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progress" Grid.Row="3" Height="20" ></ProgressBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: May be your text file is locked during write operation and cannot be reliably accessed during read of progress bar.. Try updating progress from within write operation do while after every 100 lines or so, because this not thread safe..

Comment: Well, clearly the UI's message pump thread is being blocked in some way.  In this respect, WPF doesn't really behave all that differently from Winforms.  Have you considered using a BackgroundWorker instead?

Comment: Also, won't `totalLines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"D:\test.txt").Count();` have to read the entire file to get a result?  Maybe it would be better to estimate the number of lines from the number of bytes in the file and a sampling of the first 100 lines or so to get an average line length.

Comment: @RobertHarvey counting the lines has no effect on the issue, that line is done pretty quick, its only around 50,000 lines

Comment: @numbtongue generating the file is definitely completed and streamwriter closed before moving onto the reading.  I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect your issue is that you're reporting progress too frequently. If the work that you're doing between `Report` calls is trivial (such as reading just one line from a file), then the dispatching of operations to the UI thread will become your bottleneck. Your UI dispatcher queue becomes flooded, and it won't keep up with new events such as responding to mouse clicks or moves.

To mitigate this, you should reduce the frequency of your `Report` calls to a sensible level -- for example, only calling it when a batch of 1,000 lines are processed.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(file, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    if (++i % 1000 == 0)
        progress.Report(1000);
}
```

In response to the comments: The file size doesn't matter when picking the batch size. Rather: Find a sensible target for the update frequency -- say, 100 ms. Measure or estimate the time it takes to read and process one line -- for example, 100 μs. Divide the former by the latter, and you get your answer. We picked 1,000 because we estimate that 1,000 lines would take 100 ms to process. The optimal update frequency lies around 10–100 ms, which is the limit of human perception; anything more frequent than that will not be noticed by the user.

Per the above, your 10- and 500-line files don't need to issue any updates to the UI, because they would have been processed completely in mere milliseconds, before the user has the chance to observe any progress. The 1,000,000-line file would take around 100 seconds in total, and it will update the UI 1,000 times during that period (once every 100 ms).

Comment: ok, but how do we know how frequent an update will lock the UI?  I mean what percentage of lines to report on?

Comment: Yes, I tried exactly this, and the performance improved significantly, and the progress bar actually worked.

Comment: @erotavlas: Testing and experimentation.  I tried it with 1000 lines, seems legit.

Comment: true but file sizes I'm processing are variable, one could be 10 lines, another 500, and another 1000000

Comment: The file size doesn't matter. Find a sensible target for the update frequency -- say, 100ms. Measure or estimate the time it takes to read and process one line -- for example, 100ns. Divide the former by the latter, and you get your answer.

Comment: Agreed, the file size doesn't matter.  What matters is the frequency of progress updates.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I could calculate the frequency based on percentage line count like this int frequency = (int)(totalLines * 0.001); and then                 if (++i % frequency == 0)
                    progress.Report(frequency);..I tried with a small and large file and works for both

Comment: Knock yourself out.  You probably don't even need that degree of resolution.  100 points over the entire file ought to be enough (totalLines * .01).

Comment: @erotavlas: I don't think that's the right approach. You should aim to issue updates at a fixed frequency for all files, not issue a fixed number of updates for all files. Larger files that take longer to process should generate more updates. Small files that process instantaneously don't need any updates.

Comment: @Douglas agreed

Comment: Another way to establish that frequency: just keep a tally in a common variable (use `Interlocked.Increment()`) and have a DispatcherTimer report the progression.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Good idea; that would eliminate the need to come up with estimates in advance. For completeness, you'd also need a `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` before reading the variable on the UI thread.

Comment: It will work well without a Barrier. Theoretically you might miss an increment, very rare and not observable.